# Pyinstaller failed to execute script after application closes

Tags: pyinstaller

I've constantly been running to this error `"Failed to execute script"` when I attempt to exit the application I've made. I've made 4 games with pygame and 3 apps with tkinter and they all seem to have this problem. I use the following command to convert from .py to .exe  `pyinstaller -w --onefile script.py`. Any solutions?

P.S: the app runs completely fine with no errors.

Comment: How do you exit your application? I thought you can let the program finishes itself instead of calling sys.exit()

Comment: @gfdsweds i use pygame.quit() followed by the exit() function

Comment: If you want to use `exit()`, catch the exception by `try ... except SystemExit` and `pass` it to end the program naturally.

Comment: `exit()` or `sys.exit()` throws an `SystemExit` exception, so thats why `"Failed to execute script"` is shown

Comment: [You should use `sys.exit()` instead.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) And [PyInstaller will catch that.](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/4907)